# Why mathematica does not solve the equation $x\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=10$ for $x$?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

The equation $x\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=10$ has a real solution, which is $x=\frac{10}{3}$.

But when I type

```
Solve[x*Floor[x] == 10, x]
```

a message comes: "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

Similarly with `NSolve`.

I am using version 12.1.0.0. Anything wrong I did?

Comment: A more serious issue with `Reduce[Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 == 0, x, Reals]` and  `Reduce[Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 <= 0, x, Reals]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify you want real solutions

`Solve[x*Floor[x] == 10, x, Reals]`

Comment: Unfortunately,`Solve[Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 == 0, x, Reals]` fails `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.` as well as `Reduce`. However,`NSolve[Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 == 0 && x >= 0 && 
  x <= 10, x, Reals]` works.

Comment: So does `Reduce[Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 == 0 && x >= 0 && 
  x <= 10, x, Reals]`, outputting `x == 19/4 || x == 28/5 || x == 13/2 || x == 52/7 || x == 67/8 || 
 x == 28/3`.

Comment: @user64494 `Solve[{Floor[x]^2 - x*Floor[x] + 3 == 0, 0 < x < 10}, x, Reals]` evaluates all solutions in the given interval !